# Mac struck in boot loop

Tags: boot, mac

My Mac was working yesterday and suddendly the screen started to blink. I pressed on the power button to shut it down.
Since then, I'm not able to start it...
I have tried the following things:

- Start in safe mode: It gets struck on a white screen.
- Enter recovery mode: Same.
- Enter Internet Recovery Mode: The recovery mode is loaded from Apple servers and then I get struck on the white screen again...
- I have Windows installed through bootcamp, so I have tried to start on Windows: I got struck on a black screen.
- Reset NVRAM: Changed nothing to the boot loop.
- RESET SMC: Changed nothing to the boot loop.
- Start into Verbose Mode: Changed nothing to the boot loop, after having displayed the booting info on the screen.
- Start into single user mode: I was able to boot in this mode and tried fsck. It made some fixes but when I tried to reboot after that, it doesn't change anything.

After all this attempts, I have thought that is a hardware problem. I have tried AHT and it had reported me that they were no hardware issues.

I would prefer if it were a way to retrieve my data before erasing everything.. but if not it is ok.

How can I fix this ?

I have not any bootable devices to do a clean install.. Is there a way to create one on Windows (or Ubuntu) ? I have tried TransMac but when I plugged the USB key, it was not detected on booting options.

Comment: You didn't tell us what Mac it is, so we don't know whether you can just take the drive out to diagnose on another machine. The best way to ensure your data's integrity, of course, is to just recover it from your backup.

Comment: Yep sorry. It's a late 2011 iMac

Comment: OK, options: 1. You **can** get the drive out - awkward but possible. 2. Try again with TransMac, make sure the USB is formatted GUID/HFS+; Macs won't boot from MBR.

Comment: How do i check if it ils guid hfs? I know it is not MBR as i have used diskpart and it sais written GPT

Comment: Sorry, idk on anything other than Mac.

Comment: One option other than removing the drive is if the system will boot in "Target" mode.  When booting press and hold the "t" key.  If successful you can access the drive through thunderbolt or other hardwired means.  Doesn't solve the boot issue but might let you access the data from another Mac